# Eclipse Neon3 fails while Oxygen runs fine

Tags: 16.04, java, eclipse, c++

Trying to run Eclipse Neon3 on my Ubuntu 16.04 with latest Java. Got error describe below. Newer Eclipse Oxygen runs fine. How to fix error?

```
!SESSION 2018-01-02 06:08:39.433 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=9.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-02 06:08:43.077
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:504)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:632)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        ... 25 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-01-02 06:08:43.090
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:426)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:176)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:903)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Eclipse Oxygen works without change with Java 9 (actually only Oxygen 4.7.1a and later)

Earlier releases require the eclipse.ini to be edited to add the line

```
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

in the `-vmargs` section of the file.

Only Eclipse Oxygen has full support for the Java 9 module system.